# Multiple file upload and store only one file path to MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

### This is simple html file code

```
 <form action="upme.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
      <button type="submit">Upload</button>       
 </form>
```

### This is simple PHP file code

```
<?php
$IMG = isset($_POST['files']) ? $_POST['files'] : array();

if (!empty($IMG)) 
{
$uploads_dir = 'images/';
foreach ($IMG["error"] as $key => $error)
{
  if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
{
      $tmp_name = $IMG["tmp_name"][$key];
      $name = $IMG["name"][$key];
      move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/".$name);
      $name_array=mysql_real_escape_string($name);
      $value_insert[] = "('" . $name_array . "')";
   }
}
$values_insert = implode(',', $value_insert);
  $query = "INSERT INTO upload (FILE_NAME) VALUES" . $values_insert;
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  }else{
 echo 'empty array';
  }

 ?>
```

when i use this code its give me 'empty array' error but file not upload.

Comment: $IMG = isset($_POST['files']) ? $_POST['files'] : array();  change to $IMG = isset($_FILES['files']) ? $_FILES['files'] : array();

Comment: Dear just under the html code.

Comment: @NIRANJANS its store data in db but every file store in separate db column but i want to store in a single column.

Comment: just make before foreach `$i=1;` in foreach condition `if ($i==1) {your sql query} $i++;` this will happened once.

Comment: @SamirNabil can you give the demo code,

Comment: Warning mysql_query, mysql_fetch_array,mysql_connect etc.. extensions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $IMG = isset($_FILES['files']) ? $_FILES['files'] : array();

    if (!empty($IMG)) 
    {
        $uploads_dir = 'images/';
        $value_insert = '';
        foreach ($IMG["error"] as $key => $error)
        {
            if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
            {
              $tmp_name = $IMG["tmp_name"][$key];
              $name = $IMG["name"][$key];
              move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/".$name);
              $name_array=mysql_real_escape_string($name);
              $value_insert .= $name_array . ",";
            }
        }
         $values_insert = rtrim($value_insert, ',');
          $query = "INSERT INTO upload (FILE_NAME) VALUES" . $values_insert;
          $result = mysql_query($query);
     }else{
        echo 'empty array';
     }

?>
```

Comment: every file store in separate db column but i want to store in a single column

Comment: if i change $IMG = isset($_POST['files']) ? $_POST['files'] : array(); change to $IMG = isset($_FILES['files']) ? $_FILES['files'] : array();

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: value_insert in F:\XAMPP\htdocs\uptime\upme.php on line 43

Comment: Dear its just upload the file into the folder but it not store the path in db

Comment: $query = "INSERT INTO upload (FILE_NAME) VALUES" . $values_insert; change to $query = "INSERT INTO upload (FILE_NAME) VALUES(" . $values_insert . ")";

Answer (score 0):

here is the demo code

```
<?php
$IMG = isset($_FILES['files']) ? $_FILES['files'] : array();

if (!empty($IMG)) 
{
    $uploads_dir = 'images/';
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($IMG["error"] as $key => $error)
    {
        if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
        {
          $tmp_name = $IMG["tmp_name"][$key];
          $name = $IMG["name"][$key];
          move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/".$name);
          $name_array=mysql_real_escape_string($name);
          if ($i == 1) {
             $query = "INSERT INTO upload (FILE_NAME) VALUES" . $name_array;
             $result = mysql_query($query);
             if (!$result) {
                 die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
             }
          }
          $i++;
        }
    }         

 }else{
    echo 'empty array';
 }

?>
```

Comment: its just upload the file into the folder but it not store the path into database

Comment: i just change my query $query = "INSERT INTO upload (FILE_NAME) VALUES ('$name_array');";

Comment: its work but store only  one file information in bd but i select three file.